# Can TFLite's CoreMLDelegate use GPU and CPU simultaneously in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, coreml, tensorflow-lite

I've been successfully using tflite's MetalDelegate in my app. When I switch to CoreMLDelegate, it runs my (float) tflite model (MobileNet) entirely on CPU, showing 0 GPU use. I am running this on iPhone 11MaxPro, which is a compatible device. During the initialization I noticed the following line:
“CoreML delegate: 29 nodes delegated out of 31 nodes, with 2 partitions”.
Any ideas why? How do I make  CoreMLDelegate use both GPU and CPU on iOS? I downloaded the `mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite` model file from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models).

[image]

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Metal

var device: MTLDevice!
var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!

private var total_latency:Double = 0
private var total_count:Double = 0
private var sstart = TimeInterval(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
}

// MARK: CameraFeedManagerDelegate Methods
extension ViewController: CameraFeedManagerDelegate {

  func didOutput(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    let currentTimeMs = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1
    guard (currentTimeMs - previousInferenceTimeMs) >= delayBetweenInferencesMs else { return }
    previousInferenceTimeMs = currentTimeMs



    //  1. First create the Metal device and command queue in viewDidLoad():
    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()

    var timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let start = TimeInterval(timestamp)

    // 2. Access the shared MTLCaptureManager and start capturing
    let capManager = MTLCaptureManager.shared()
    let myCaptureScope = capManager.makeCaptureScope(device: device)
    myCaptureScope.begin()
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
    // Do Metal work


    // Pass the pixel buffer to TensorFlow Lite to perform inference.
    result = modelDataHandler?.runModel(onFrame: pixelBuffer)


    // 3.
    // encode your kernel
    commandBuffer.commit()
    myCaptureScope.end()

    timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let end = TimeInterval(timestamp)
    //var end = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(myTimeInterval))

    total_latency += (end - start)
    total_count += 1;
    let rfps = total_count/(end - sstart)
    let fps = total_count/(end - start)
    let stri = "Time: " + String(end - start) + " avg: " + String(total_latency/total_count)+" count: " + String(total_count)+" rfps: "+String(rfps)+" fps: "+String(fps)
    print(stri)


    // Display results by handing off to the InferenceViewController.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      guard let finalInferences = self.result?.inferences else {
        self.resultLabel.text = ""
        return
      }
     let resultStrings = finalInferences.map({ (inference) in
        return String(format: "%@ %.2f",inference.label, inference.confidence)
      })
      self.resultLabel.text = resultStrings.joined(separator: "\n")
    }

  }
```

2020-08-22 07:09:39.783215-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] coreml_version must be 2 or 3. Setting to 3.
2020-08-22 07:09:39.785103-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] Created TensorFlow Lite delegate for Metal.
2020-08-22 07:09:39.785505-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-08-22 07:09:39.786110-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-08-22 07:09:39.927854-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
2020-08-22 07:09:39.928928-0400 ImageClassification[3039:645963] CoreML delegate: 29 nodes delegated out of 31 nodes, with 2 partitions

Comment: If you're using 11MaxPro, it has the neural engine, which will be used by the CoreML delegate by default. In that case, it is expected that your GPU is not used (i.e. the neural engine is a separate accelerator, different from GPU). Have you tried comparing the latency benchmarks with and without the CoreML delegate?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, @yyoon. Yes, I have tried both. MetalDelegate is giving me 120 FPS, CPU 1.5 ms, GPU 0.4 ms per frame, energy impact - very high. With CoreMLDelegate I get 26 FPS, CPU 38.6 ms, GPU 0 ms, energy impact - high. Without any acceleration the model runs at 20 FPS with 51,2 ms frame time and energy use - very high. So it is tricky to decide. Firstly I want to find out what the maximum achievable FPS is in my case, and secondly, I want to find "most efficient" way of running it in terms of both: energy use and FPS

Comment: That doesn't match the expectation. For MobilenetV1, the CoreML delegate should actually give similar FPS with the GPU, and should be much faster than vanilla TFLite. Can you try measuring the average latency with the official benchmark app for iOS? https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement#ios_benchamark_app

Comment: @yyoon, in benchmark app Startup latency: 397.347 ms

Inference:
 - Num runs: 312
 - Average: 3.16502 ms
 - Min: 2.857 ms 
 - Max: 3.575 ms 
 - Std deviation: 0.116 ms

Warmup:
 - Num runs: 149
 - Average: 3.31269 ms
 - Min: 2.78 ms 
 - Max: 7.151 ms 
 - Std deviation: 0.616 ms

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying out Core ML delegate. Can you share the version of TFLite you used, and a code that you used to initialize Core ML delegate? Also, can you confirm that you're trying to run float model, not quantized one?

the latency might be different depending on what you measure, but when measuring solely the inference time my iPhone 11 Pro shows 11ms for CPU, and 5.5ms for Core ML delegate.

Neural Engine utilization is not captured by profiler, but if you're seeing that latency and high CPU utilization, it might indicate your model is running solely on CPU. You can also try the [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/) to figure out which part is consuming the most resources.

Comment: Hello @Taehee Jeong
I used  
`pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift', '~> 0.0.1-nightly', :subspecs => ['Metal', 'CoreML'] `

The initialization commands in swift:

`var options = CoreMLDelegate.Options()`,
`options.enabledDevices = .all`,

`let coreMLDelegate = CoreMLDelegate(options: options)!`,

`interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath, delegates: [coreMLDelegate] )`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.For the benchmark app, it only measures Swift equivalent of Interpreter.invoke(). Can you check if you're doing that in your app too, or is there other codes that you're including in the time measurement?

Comment: Hello, @Taehee Jeong

During initialization I noticed this line: 
“CoreML delegate: 29 nodes delegated out of 31 nodes, with 2 partitions”. 

As for your previous questions, 
The mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite file comes from [here]( https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models
). 
I was measuring duration of the `result = modelDataHandler?.runModel(onFrame: pixelBuffer)` command inside my `didOutput(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer)` function (see code sample in updated question). I also used instruments tool and saw no neural engine calls during inference with coreml delegate.